# Backup a local working directory on BitBucket - clone or push

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I am very new to version control, so my questions are very basic. I am trying to use Mercurial for the purpose. I have a local working directory on my mac. I want to use Bitbucket to backup the files and the repository in this directory.

Will the following command:

```
hg push localDirectoryWithRepo http://bitbucker.org/user_name/repo_on_bitbucket
```

transfer my files also to Bitbucket, or only the repository?

Also, I tried the command:

```
hg clone localDirectoryWithRepo http://bitbucker.org/user_name/repo_on_bitbucket
```

however, I get the error saying

```
abort: cannot create new http repository
```

How do I clone a local working directory on bitbucket initially and then update a working directory on bitbucket, so that it is the same as my local working directory.

As always, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial only transfers committed changes.  It will not help you backup working copies you aren't ready to commit.  The `push` command sends every committed changeset the remote repo doesn't have and the clone command sends (or gets) all of them to a location that doesn't already have a repo -- and bitbucket doesn't support creating new repos on their end using close.

Commit early.  Commit often.  Push often.